# Fluxbox compiling problems after making a change

Tags: window-managers

I'm trying to make the change here: http://fluxbox-wiki.org/index.php?title=Howto_Make_dblclick_titlebar_maximize

I am using the current git version of the fluxbox source.

I assume that those instructions are perhaps no longer valid for the current git version.

In the void FluxboxWindow::setupWindow() function I can see no references to CommandRef or frame.

I would like to know if it is possible that I could work out where they should go in that function, with only having a limited knowledge?

I am still trying to learn programming and don't know enough just yet to work out where they should go. I assume I can't just paste in the suggested lines anywhere in that function, but why not?

I can paste the source if needed, but I am unsure where to paste to.

Comment: Yes, a long time ago I made this trick for my fluxbox on gentoo, but unfortunately don't remember all the details... In my opinion, you need to search something like *frame().setOnDoubleClickTitlebar(maximize_cmd, 1,true);* function...

Comment: Hi mosg, I've got that I just don't know where to put it. frame or commandref is not called at all from the setupWindow function, from what I can see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Editing the source is no longer necessary. Read man fluxbox-keys.

Comment: Keyboard shortcuts have absolutely nothing to do with the link I posted, and what I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: Why doesn't anybody ever believe me? http://git.fluxbox.org/?p=fluxbox.git;a=blobdiff;f=ChangeLog;h=353af012b6d7ae2fcde72c72ab5b83ec3185b544;hp=5971f05443443af67ddf740534766a0af2f176dd;hb=95f9c2d6806cf110597a992be45b17a3b13accd7;hpb=0b416600779f9e3560eab178e3e4abfb09793d30

Comment: Mark, I'm very sorry, you were exactly 100% right. My apologies.